# How to create hidden window in background js

Tags: javascript

I want to create window in background which will be invisible for users. I tried it so

```
//background.js
 chrome.windows.create({url:'https://mobile.facebook.com/friends/center/requests/?rfj', focused:false, state:"minimized"}, function(hiddenWindow){

    });
```

but it does not work. Can someone help me please? i want to open hidden window with its link

Comment: I'm an internet user and I don't want websites to open background windows, thank you very much. Thankfully, browsers started preventing that kind of practice sometime around the turn of the century.

Comment: you can't do what you want to do.  Depending on your ultimate goal you could conceivably load page content into a hidden div and show that as a floating window as needed.  Bootstrap can do this as well as kendo but it's not terribly hard in javascript.